# Optimize a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is a code snippet that shows the code I would like to optimize:

```
result = [(item, foo(item))
          for item in item_list
          if cond1(item) and cond2(foo(item))]
```

In the above snippet I call `foo(item)` twice. I can't think of a way to iterate over the list only once maintain both `item` and `foo(item)` for the conditional and the result list.

That is, I would like to keep `item` and `foo(item)` without having to loop over the list twice and without having to call `foo(item)` twice.

I know I can do it with a second nested list comprehension:

```
result = [(item, foo_item)
          for item, foo_item in [(i, foo(i)) for i in item_list]
          if cond1(item) and cond2(foo_item)]
```

but that appears to loop through `item_list` twice which I would like to avoid.

So the first example calls `foo` twice per list item. The second example loops through the list twice (or appears to). I'd like to loop one time and call `foo` once for each item.

Comment: It would be great if you could test the performance of the various answers and post the results here. It's a bit hard for anyone else to do it without knowing the running time of `cond1`,`cond2` and `foo`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't, but here:

```
result = [(item, foo_item)
    for item, foo_item in ((i, foo(i)) for i in item_list)
    if cond1(item) and cond2(foo_item)]
```

Turning the inner list comprehension into a generator expression makes sure that we don't use an unnecessary temporary list.

Comment: That is identical to my second example except you have changed my list comprehension into a generator expression. Are you saying that my second example would only look through the list once? Or are you saying that in order for it to only loop once I need a generator expression?

Comment: A list comprehension creates a list. So you iterate over `item_list`, applying the function to each element in turn, and returning the results as a list. You then iterate over *this* list, making it appear as though you're iterating over `item_list` twice when in fact it's just a side effect of the algorithm.

Comment: The example with inner list will iterate through whole item_list to create a temporary list and then iterate through that list.
The example with generator will iterate through item_list and for each item execute the rest of the code - exactly what you asked for.

Comment: So there are 2 iterations. Once for `item_list` and once for the new list generated by the inner comprehension. Which is as I suspected. I want to avoid that second iteration so that I only ever iterate over `len(list)` regardless of how many intermediate lists are created.

Comment: Which is what converting it to a genex does.

Comment: Is your problem that you _think_ it loops over the list twice, or that it _looks_ like it loops over the loop twice?  If the former, I don't think we can help.  If the latter, I think the question is a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Like I've been repeatedly told here,
the best thing in such cases is not to use a list comprehension at all:

```
result = []
for item in item_list:
    if cond1(item):
        value = foo(item)
        if cond2(value):
            result.append((item, value))
```

But I am stubbborn, so let's see what I can come up with (and keep the comprehension)
(oh, wait -- I got your code all wrong. Still - unwrapping and having intermediate variables is the straight way for not to repeat the call)

Comment: I'm the same. Obviously it can be written efficiently imperatively but I am interested in a functional or list-comprehension based solution.

Comment: +1 This is simple, readable and likely to be the fastest. Anyone care to run some benchmarks?

Answer (score 3):

How does this look?

```
result = [ (i, fi) for i  in item_list if cond1(i)
                   for fi in (foo(i),) if cond2(fi) ]
```

Comment: That is pretty slick actually. I wonder if the packaging and unpacking of `foo(i)` into a list is expensive. Still it is a clean way to solve the problem. I'll give it some thought.

Comment: I would hope that creating a list (or a single-element tuple) uses a highly-optimized code path in the Python interpreter. It has to be faster than creating and iterating through a generator.  I welcome comments from someone who's actually benchmarked these suggestions.

Comment: Good -  I was coming now to retry assigning foo[i] to some "thing" (like a locals().__setitem__ call) but this single-item for is much cleaner.  (again, just for the fun of making it in one line)

Comment: This calculates `foo(i)` regardless of the result of `cond1(i)`. When `cond1(i)` is `False` you should avoid calculating `foo(i)`

Comment: @gnibbler: it's an easy fix. I was trying to preserve the way the poster originally structured the question.  You're right, this is the better way to write it.

Answer (score 3):

Use generator expressions.

```
result = [(item, foo_item)
          for item, foo_item in ((i, foo(i)) for i in item_list)
          if cond1(item) and cond2(foo_item)]
```

The interpreter will go through every element exactly once, because generator expression will calculate `(i, foo(i))` only when it is required by the outer loop.

Assuming that `foo` is expensive and has no side effects, I'd even try to do this:

```
result = [(item, foo_item)
          for item, foo_item in ((i, foo(i)) for i in item_list if cond1(i))
          if cond2(foo_item)]
```

so that foo will not be called for elements which do not pass the first condition. Actually this looks better for me when written functionally:

```
from itertools import imap, ifilter
result = filter((lambda i,f:cond2(f)),
           imap((lambda i:(i, foo(i))),
             ifilter(cond1, item_list)))
```

...but I might be subjective.

Comment: It would be natural to move the conditional into the generator expression to reduce it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the many reasons that we have generators:

```
def generator( items ):
    for item in items:
        if cond1(item):
            food = foo(item)
            if food:
                yield item, food

result = list(generator(item_list))
```

LCs are only good when they look good - if you have to spread them over 3 lines just to make them readable it's a bad idea.